# How to convert a one-dimensional tensor containing only one element to a 0-D tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume that `a` is the one-dimensional tensor containing only one element. The operation which we are about to perform requires us to pass a 0-D tensor. For example, [tf.range()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) where the start, limit and delta values have to be 0-D tensors and we have the values of start, limit and delta coming to us in the form of intermediate results of a computation and hence are in the shape as `[1]`. How do we convert them to a scalar?

Answer (score 0):

When we declare a constant as follows:
`a = tf.constant(5, dtype = tf.int32)`
then the value we get is a scalar constant.
On printing its shape we get:
`In[1]: se = tf.Session()`
`In[2]: se.run(tf.shape(a))`
`Out[2]: array([], dtype=int32)`

Instead if `a` would have been of the form

`a = tf.constant([5], dtype = tf.int32)`

the shape would come as

`In[3]: se.run(tf.shape(a))`
`Out[3]: array([1], dtype=int32)`

**Final Answer**

The above results clear it out that if `a` would have been a one dimensional tensor, in order to convert it to a scalar all we have to do is
`In[4]: tf.reshape(a, shape = [])`